Why does my Google Service Account not see files shared with it, but can see files created with it?
I am using the Python Client to amend a Google Sheet shared to a Google Service Account.
Everything works as expected when using a Sheet that is created by the Service Account, but returns a Requested entity was not found error when accessing a Google Sheet that is owned by someone else but shared with the service account.
I have tried with all combinations of these definitions:

Personal Google account (i.e. @gmail.com)
Workspace Google account
Service Account with "shared outside domain set" with Drive and Sheets APIs enabled
"Stock" Service account with Drive and Sheets APIs enabled
Shared the containing folder of the Sheet
Shared just the Sheet itself

Can anyone point to what I could be doing wrong that would mean that the client can find a sheet that it creates, but not one that is shared with it?


Can anyone point to what I could be doing wrong that would mean that the client can find a sheet that it creates, but not one that is shared with it?

There is a scope in  Google drive, which is characteristic of your description:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files you use with this app

If you're using that scope, change to a more permissive scope like
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive


Oh my... that's probably it. I'll be able to check in a couple of hours, but in the meantime thank you for the lead and hope!

That absolutely was it, thank you so much @TheMaster.
